# Dynamics CRM 2016 Plugin triggered when user role assignments are changed

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

Is it possible in Dynamics CRM 2016 to have a plugin that fires when any user's role assignments are changed?

If so, what message and entity would I register this plugin on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to register plugin to Associate message,primary and secondary entity as none.

In plugin, you need to check for context.MessageName ("Associate" or "Disassociate") and context.InputParameters[“Relationship”] (we are looking for "systemuserroles_association")

code to check conditions would be something like that

```
//all usual plugin stuff here

if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Relationship")) {
    relationshipName = context.InputParameters["Relationship"].ToString();
}                                   

// Check the “Relationship Name” with your intended one
if (relationshipName != "systemuserroles_association") {
    return;
} 

if (context.MessageName == "Associate") {
    //logic when role added
}
if (context.MessageName == "Disassociate") {
    //logic when role removed
}
else {
    //not interested
}
```

I haven't compiled the code, but it should give you idea how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register **two** plugins:

1) Will work when a user **associate** with a security role. For this you should register plugin to Associate message.

2) Will work when a user **disassociate** with a security role. For this you should register plugin to Disassociate message.

In both plugins you should check *systemuserroles_association* relationship name like that:

```
if (localContext.PluginExecutionContext.InputParameters.Contains("Relationship"))
    relationshipName = ((Relationship)localContext.PluginExecutionContext.InputParameters["Relationship"]).SchemaName;
else return;

if (!relationshipName.Equals("systemuserroles_association", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    return;
```

After that you can get Target (User) and RelatedEntities (Security Roles) and do your stuff:

```
// Target
if (localContext.PluginExecutionContext.InputParameters.Contains("Target") && localContext.PluginExecutionContext.InputParameters["Target"] is EntityReference)
{
    EntityReference targetEntity = (EntityReference)localContext.PluginExecutionContext.InputParameters["Target"];
    userId = targetEntity.Id;
}
// RelatedEntities
if (localContext.PluginExecutionContext.InputParameters.Contains("RelatedEntities") && localContext.PluginExecutionContext.InputParameters["RelatedEntities"] is EntityReferenceCollection)
{
    // Collection of SecurityRoles
    EntityReferenceCollection relatedEntities = localContext.PluginExecutionContext.InputParameters["RelatedEntities"] as EntityReferenceCollection;
}
```